# Sql query to join two tables and represent null values for no matches

Tags: mysql, join

I got 2 tables

Table1:

```
id|name1
-----
1|Tom
2|Tom
```

Table 2:

```
id|name2
-----
1|Tom
1|Lucy
1|Frank
2|Tom
2|John
```

The code I used :

```
select a.id,a.name,b.name from table1 a
join table 2 b
on a.id=b.id 
group by 1,2,3;
```

The output I got:

```
id|name1|name2
1|Tom|Tom
1|Tom|Lucy
1|Tom|Frank
2|Tom|Tom
2|Tom|John
```

My Desired output:

```
id|name1|name2
1|Tom|Tom
1|Null|Lucy
1|Null|Frank
2|Tom|Tom
2|Null|John
```

A simple left-join does not work here
I'm trying to obtain null values for no matches.
I'm using MySQL 8.0
You can work your code here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b389d8e94b4b2f4e6188ca8e833b6d6f
Thank you.

Comment: Put everything needed to ask your post in your post, not just at a link. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Comment: Please don't [repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62580291/3404097), edit them. Don't make us repeat our reading & commenting & closing. Act on the comments & close vote messages. All poorly received questions count towards posting bans, deleted or not. PS Explain re being stuck. We can expect this to be a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `left join` of `table2` to `table1`:

```
select t2.id, t1.name1, t2.name2
from table2 t2 left join table1 t1
on t1.name1 = t2.name2 and t2.id = t1.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0cb6fe516fd18786707982e2b9caafcd).
Results:

```
> id | name1 | name2
> -: | :---- | :----
>  1 | Tom   | Tom  
>  1 | null  | Lucy 
>  1 | null  | Frank
>  2 | Jen   | Jen  
>  2 | null  | John
```

Comment: this works when there are no duplicates in names. 
But what if there are duplicates?
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a6f979c7aa9730936841a7d89bc2e98s